# Why is the path included in conda prompt and how can I shorten it

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed miniconda3 to my system a while ago (on linux). One of things which has become very annoying, is that when I source activate an environment which I have created, not including the base environment, the prompt displays the full path to my miniconda install instead of just the environment name.

How can I get it to just display the environment name instead of the full path and name.

For reference, here is my environment list

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3
eof37                    /scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/eof37
```

here is my prompt using base

```
(base) [XXXXXX@server ~]$
```

and here is my prompt using another created environment

```
(/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/eof37) [XXXXXX@server ~]$
```

and I would ideally like this prompt to be

```
(eof37) [XXXXXX@server ~]$
```

instead

EDIT: further info - conda lines in my .bashrc

```
# added by Miniconda3 4.5.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
            . "/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
            CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
            \export PATH="/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

EDIT 2: output of `conda config --show`

```
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
allow_non_channel_urls: False
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: None
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/free: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: ["https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r", "https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro"]
  local: []
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro
disallowed_packages: []
download_only: False
envs_dirs:
  - /scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3
  - /scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/envs
  - /home/XXXXXX/.conda/envs
extra_safety_checks: False
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
max_shlvl: 2
migrated_channel_aliases: []
no_dependencies: False
non_admin_enabled: True
notify_outdated_conda: True
offline: False
override_channels_enabled: True
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - /scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/pkgs
  - /home/XXXXXX/.conda/pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
report_errors: None
rollback_enabled: True
safety_checks: warn
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
ssl_verify: True
track_features: []
use_index_cache: False
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
whitelist_channels: []
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant lines in your `.bashrc`? What version of conda do you have? This is hard to answer because there are so many ways for this change to be made... How are you activating conda when you login?

Comment: I've added the lines in my bashrc related to conda above. The conda version is 4.5.12.

Directly after login I run `source activate env_name` to activate my conda enviroments

Comment: Can you try `conda activate` instead of `source activate`? Can you also include the output of `conda config --show`?

Comment: using `conda activate` gives me the same long prompt as `source activate`. So same problem still. I've added the output of `conda config --show` above

Comment: That is very strange. Can you change the config `conda config --set changeps1 False` and try again in a new shell?

Comment: Tried that but now the prefix on the prompt has dropped. The prompt is now `[XXXXXX@server ~]$` whilst I would like it to be  `(eof37) [XXXXXX@server ~]$`.

ps. Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved, but just for future reference here is how I did it.

Basically, when the envs are in a custom path (e.g. `/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3` in your case), conda prompts the full path. To make it prompt only the env name, move (or copy) your env directory at the default path (`/scratch/XXXXXX/miniconda3/envs`) and remove your custom path from `.condarc`.